# React native navigation between 2 screens

Tags: reactjs, navigation, native

I am new in react native and I don't understand why it is not working
In my main file App.js , I need to have a button to go to another screen( AddList.js)
So, In app.js , I have
`function App (navigation) {`
`const onPressHandler = () => {`
`navigation.navigate('AddList')`
`}`
`return (`
`<Pressable onPress={onPressHandler}>}`

`function addList(navigation) {`
`const onPressHandler = () => {`
`navigation.goBack();`
`}`
`return(`
`<NavigationContainer>`
`<Stack.Navigator>`
`<Stack.Screen`
`name="Home"`
`component={App}`
`/>`
`<Stack.Screen`
`name="FavProducts"`
`component={FavProducts}`
`/>`

```
  </Stack.Navigator>

</NavigationContainer>
)
```

`}`

There are in the same file App.js

Sorry for the question and thanks to your help

I have try with reactnative doc , but not working

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 2):

If you are using **@react-navigation/native** then first you need to create container to handle the component state and then you have to create stack
in side the stack you need to define your screens like this.

```
import React from 'react';

import { NavigationContainer } from "@react-navigation/native";
import { createStackNavigator } from "@react-navigation/stack";

import AddList from './components/screens/AddList';

const Stack = createStackNavigator();

const App = () => {

return (
 <NavigationContainer>
  <Stack.Navigator>
   <Stack.Screen
    component={AddList}
    name="AddList"
    options={{ headerShown: false }}
   />
  // define your screens as well
</Stack.Navigator>


</NavigationContainer>
 );
};
export default App;
```

and if you have to move from one screen to another then import in your js file where you have to create the click event

```
import { useNavigation } from '@react-navigation/native';
const navigation = useNavigation();
```

and on button press

```
navigation.navigate('AddList')
```